# MakeBoxes not allowing alternatives defined through variable

Tags: output-formatting

I've encountered an issue where using `Alternatives[...]` indirectly through a variable within MakeBoxes does not seem to work, and I was wondering why this might be.

As a simple example, consider the following:

```
altPattern = 1 | 2 | 3;

f1 /: MakeBoxes[f1[n : (1 | 2 | 3)], TraditionalForm] := With[
  {
    nText = Switch[n
      ,
      1, "one",
      2, "two",
      3, "three"
    ]
  },
  RowBox[{"Foo", "(", nText, ")"}]
]

f2 /: MakeBoxes[f2[n : altPattern], TraditionalForm] := With[
  {
    nText = Switch[n
      ,
      1, "one",
      2, "two",
      3, "three"
    ]
  },
  RowBox[{"Foo", "(", nText, ")"}]
]
```

As far as I can tell, both `f1` and `f2` should behave the same, yet Mathematica thinks otherwise:

[image: output]

Furthermore, the output from looking at the definition looks fine, with `f2` using the `altPattern` as expected and `f1` using the explicit form.

Furthermore, the issue seems to occur only in association with MakeBoxes as the following works fine:

```
f1[n : (1 | 2 | 3)] := 2 n
f2[n : altPattern] := 2 n

f1[1]  (* 2 *)
f2[2]  (* 2 *)
```

Comment: `MakeBoxes` is `HoldAllComplete`, so `altPattern` doesn't evaluate.

Comment: So is there a way around this, is this just impossible to do?